# How to allow a particular role like Contributor be able to only view pending comments and approve them?

Tags: comments, user-roles

I want to allow Contributor role, of which does not have access to Comments (if it was allowed I disabled with adminimizer), to be able to view only Pending comments, and be allowed to approve the pending comments. But not allowed to see approved comments.

How can this be done?